# Configure bluetooth adapters individually

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have two bluetooth adapters on my laptop: one onboard and one usb dongle. I would like to configure them to have different defaults. For example, I want the onboard device to be brought up automatically, but the usb device to stay down until brought up manually. I'd also like to configure different names, device classes, and uuids. Is this possible with BlueZ? Settings like `AutoEnable=true` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` get applied to all controllers indiscriminately and the individual settings files in `/var/lib/bluetooth/<bdaddr>` only seem to work for a small subset of the config properties in main.conf.